# How to get location (longitude and latitude) from json data show on map?

Tags: javascript

I am using Openlayers module to have a map. In my json, it has longitude and latitude field. I want to get them to show on map so that user can see the location with the marker.

Is there any way to help me solve this problem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: All relevant: 
[Getting Started with OpenLayers in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/1481374), 
[Custom Markers](https://drupal.org/node/1585880), 
[Using custom markers instead of default marker (Openlayers)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814897/using-custom-markers-instead-of-default-marker-openlayers), 
[OpenLayers.Marker](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html)

Answer (score 1):

1) Add Geofield in your content type.

2) Select widget type as "Latitude / Longitude". 
Here you can store values and show it on map.

For your reference listed some links :

[Setting drupal 7 locations](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/mmueggenborg/2012/01/03/setting-drupal-7-locations-map)

[Getting Started with OpenLayers in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/1481374)

[Openlayers](http://beautiful7mind.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/building-maps-using-openlayers-in-drupal-7/)